# CSS connected menu to div background

Tags: css, menu

I'm currently coding this template: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJFhD.png

I want it to look like this, but whenever I do this, that's what's happening: http://gyazo.com/a87d0c8f763ec1875d74f238ed8ff575

My code: http://pastebin.com/4WPUGiaT

What did I do wrong?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>SlyFiles</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="SlyFiles upload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script><!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links --><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">$(window).load(function() {  $('.flexslider').flexslider({    animation: "slide"  });});</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<header>
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
   <li class="current"><img src="img/home.png"/><span style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px;">Home</span></li>
   <li><img src="img/twitter.png"/><span style="pical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px;">Twitter</span></li>
   <li><img src="img/fb.png"/><span style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px;">Facebook</span></li>
   <li><img src="img/contact.png"/><span style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px;">Contact</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="borderbottom"></div>
</header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
.header  {
height: 42px;
width: 100%;
background: #1d1d1d;
}

#borderbottom {
width: 100%;
height: 12px;
background-image: url("../img/border.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.menu {
margin-top: -15px;
}
.menu li {
display: inline;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
color: #fff;
}

.current {
background-image: url("../img/current.png");
width: 84px;
height: 54px;
}

.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;}
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}


/* FlexSlider Default Theme
*********************************/
.flexslider {margin: 0 0 60px; background: #fff; border: 4px solid #fff; position: relative; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -o-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); zoom: 1;}
.flex-viewport {max-height: 258px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease;}
.loading .flex-viewport {max-height: 300px;}
.flexslider .slides {zoom: 1;}

.carousel li {margin-right: 5px}


/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav {*height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav a {width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 0 0; display: block; background: url(images/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {left: -36px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next {opacity: 0.8; right: 5px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev {opacity: 0.8; left: 5px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {opacity: .3!important; filter:alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default;}

/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: -40px; text-align: center;}
.flex-control-nav li {margin: 0 6px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;}
.flex-control-paging li a {
width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -o-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 }

.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
background: #009ec3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%, #00aad9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#009ec3), color-stop(100%,#00aad9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#009ec3', endColorstr='#00aad9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

 }
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
background: #009ec3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%, #00aad9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#009ec3), color-stop(100%,#00aad9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #009ec3 0%,#00aad9 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#009ec3', endColorstr='#00aad9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

 cursor: default;
 }

.flex-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {opacity: 1; left: 0;}
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 35: You have not specified an `</span>` tag.

(On this line: `<li><img src="img/contact.png"/><span style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px;">Contact</li>`).